# Postgresql and .Net - Connection Pooling with Multiple Endpoints

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

**Basic Intro:**

Connection string: `Host=IP;Port=somePort;Username=someUser;Password=somePass;Database=someDb;Maximum Pool Size=100`

My web application has several dozen endpoints available via WS and HTTP. Every one of these endpoints opens a new NPGSQL connection (all using the same connection string as above), processes data, then closes via the `using` statement.

**Issue:**
When the application restarts for an update, there is typically 2-3,000 users all reconnecting. This typically leads to errors regarding the connection pool being full and new connections being rejected due to too many clients already. However, once it can finally come online it typically only uses between 5-10 connections at any given time.

**Question:**
Is the logic below the proper way to use connection pooling? With every endpoint creating a new NPGSQL connection using the same connection string specifying a connection pool of 100?

It seems that the connection pool often shoots right up to 100, but ~80/100 of those connections are shown as idle in a DB viewer with new connection requests being denied due to pool overflow.

**Better option?**
I could also try and force a more "graceful" startup by slowly allowing new users to re-connect, but I'm not sure if the logic for creating a new connection with every endpoint is correct.

```
// DB Connection String - Used for all NPGSQL connections
const string connectionStr "Host=IP;Port=somePort;Username=someUser;Password=somePass;Database=someDb;Maximum Pool Size=100";

// Endpoint 1 available via Websocket
public async Task someRequest(someClass someArg)
{
    /* Create a new SQL connection for this user's request using the same global connections string */
    using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStr);
    conn.Open();

    /* Call functions and pass this SQL connection for any queries to process this user request */
    somefunction(conn, someArg);
    anotherFunction(conn, someArg);

    /* Request processing is done */
    /* conn is closed automatically by the "using" statement above */
}

// Endpoint 2 available via Websocket
public async Task someOtherRequest(someClass someArg)
{
    /* Create a new SQL connection for this user's request using the same global connections string */
    using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStr);
    conn.Open();

    /* Call functions and pass this SQL connection for any queries to process this user request */
    somefunction(conn, someArg);
    anotherFunction(conn, someArg);

    /* Request processing is done */
    /* conn is closed automatically by the "using" statement above */
}

// endpoint3();
// endpoint4();
// endpoint5();
// endpoint6();
// etc.
```

**EDIT:**
I've made the change suggested, by closing connections and sending them back to the pool during processing. However, the issue still persists on startup.

1. Application startup - 100 connections claimed for pooling. Almost all of them are idle. Application receives connection pool exhaustion errors, little to no transactions are even processed.
2. Transactions suddenly start churning, not sure why? Is this after some sort of timeout perhaps? I know there was some sort of 300 second timeout default in documentation somewhere... this might match up here.
3. Transactions lock up again, pool exhaustion errors resume.
4. Transactions spike and resume, user requests start coming through again.
5. Application levels out as normal.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
This startup issue seems to consistently be taking 5 minutes from startup to clear a deadlock of idle transactions and start running all of the queries.

I know 5 minutes is the default value for `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`. However, I tried running `SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '30s';` and `10s` during the startup this time and it didn't seem to impact it at all.

I'm not sure why those 100 pooled connections would be stuck in idle like that on startup, taking 5 minutes to clear and allow queries to run if that's the case...

Comment: Yeah i'd argue if you are creating and then disposing of connections you're effectively throwing out connection pooling. But ideally you'd get some info from someone like Shay Rojansky to find out if NPGSQL would return the connection to the pool under this very specific use case.

Comment: @ziatsman unless Pooling has been disabled in the connection string (and it hasn't), then disposing a connection returns it to the pool. So connection pooling definitely is not thrown out.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I've implemented the suggestion regarding closing the connections in-between data processing. I've added an edit to the post with some visuals on the SQL connections/transactions, the same issue still persists on startup. Any idea what would cause the connections to lock up like that?

Comment: I don't see evidence of a connection leak, as the application will run for days or weeks with a steady hover of ~5 active connections at anytime. This issue is only with the initial startup burst.

Comment: Latest startup took about 5 minutes exactly to start allowing a bit transaction burst in. It seems the pool is filled up with 100 dead/idle/locked connections at startup. This matches with the default `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` but running `SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '30s';` while it was locked didn't seem to help at all.

Comment: It's hard to understand from your description exactly what's going on... The fact that there are many idle connections (in the pool) is normal; after an initial spike - during which many physical connections get created - these connection hang around for a while until pruned (that's the point of pooling).

Comment: If you're seeing pool exhaustion errors, it could be because your activity spike surpasses your configured Max Pool Size, i.e. more than 100 connections are needed concurrently. It's true that you shouldn't be seeing exhaustion errors and *at the same time* be seeing idle connections in the pool, though it isn't clear from your description if that's the case. It's also not entirely clear how transactions relate to all of this.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to put together some sort of simple, minimal repro (e.g. in a console program) that attempts to approximate your problematic startup scenario... If you manage to do that, you can also share that sample for everyone to understand better.

Comment: With some data from `pg_stat_activity` on startup, it appears all 100 connections are locked in the idle state for the `ClientRead` `wait_event`. These idle connections are all stuck waiting for the query to read back and don't time out until 5 minutes later.

My idea is to lower the timeout for idle queries and to implement some form of "warm up" when the application restarts and needs to log back in a few thousand users.

Comment: It seems to just get overwhelmed trying to instantly process thousands of queries on a restart event. If those initial queries don't get a response it locks them waiting for the full timeout, and keeps the connection pool filled with these idle connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten to update this post with some of the latest information. There was a few other internal optimizations I had made in the code.

One of the major ones, was simply changing `conn.Open();` to `await conn.OpenAsync();` and `conn.Close();` to `conn.CloseAsync();`.

Everything else I had was properly async, but there was still IO blocking for all of the new connections in NPGSQL, causing worse performance with large bursts.

A very obvious change, but I didn't even think to look for an async method for the connections opening and closing.

Answer (score 1):

A connection is released to the pool once you close it in your code. From what you wrote, you are keeping it open for the entire time of a request, so basically 1 user = 1 connection and pooling is just used as a waiting room (`timeout` setting, 15 seconds by default). Open/Close the connection each time you need to access the DB, so the connection is returned to the pool and can be used by another user when time is spent in .net code.

Example, in pseudo code:

```
Enter function  
 Do some computations in .net, like input validation

  Open connection (grab it from the pool)
    Fetch info#1  
  Close connection (return it to the pool)

 Do some computations in .net, like ordering the result, computing an age from a date etc 
  
  Open connection (grab it from the pool)
    Fetch info #2   
  Close connection (return it to the pool)

 Do some computations in .net

Return
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation - especially if there's other computation or long process happening where you're not using the database: you don't want to needlessly keep a connection during that. Opening and closing (or disposing) are highly optimized when using pooling, so there's very little overhead.

Comment: I see, typically the entire request/function opens at the start and closes at the end of the processing with the using statement - so I can optimize this then.

But other than opening/closing it more frequently in-between data processing, "opening" a new connection with that connection string is the best practice for every endpoint?

Comment: I was somewhat confused on the connection pool overflow errors when using a DB viewer like DBeaver was showing ~80/100 of those connections as idle, and only a few of them were still active. Is this a connection limit it's hitting on the DB side of things, not the connection string? Or are those live performance graphs just misleading perhaps? EDIT: Or... maybe that's just because the connections are idle while my code is processing/manipulating data... thus why the suggestion above could help.

Comment: yes, you "open" (either establish a new connection OR get an already open one from the pool) each time you call the DB, so in your example multiple times per endpoint. NPGSQL will recognize it is the same connection string and will handle the pool accordingly.

Comment: For the idle connections, it's hard to say without more information. It is OK to have them idle (they are open, in the pool, available for other requests) but then your code shouldn't error-out saying there is no more connection available! It can be because your code is maintaining them open (doing something else, or purely not closing them, ever, waiting for the garbage collector to do it (though that's unlikely because of the `using`))

Comment: My guess was they are idle while that connection is still open but data processing is being ran. Would there be any difference in using conn.close() vs conn.closeAsync() in-between queries for a function? My guess is I wouldn't want to await returning the connection back to the pool. I just use conn.open() as well vs .openAsync(). All of my queries are async, but not the open/closing of the connection.